# using VBA how can I send a selection of Excel Cells to an Email Body with html formatting?

Tags: html, vba, excel, email

I have grabbed a range of cells from my Excel Worksheet, but for each cell in the range I am wanting to add a **string** + **opening html**, then add **cell 1** from range I grabbed from my Excel sheet, then add **closing html**, and finally move to **cell 2** in the range. Repeating the process for the next string + opening html + cell 2 + closing html.

The method I am using currently is incorrect as it is placing **ALL** the strings, html and the current cell to the body every time, and then moving to cell 2 in the range!

**Here is my code so far:**

```
Sub Email_Figures_Click()

    'Lets dim the things we need
    Dim CDO_Mail As Object
    Dim CDO_Config As Object
    Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strCc As String
    Dim strBcc As String
    Dim myRng As Range

    'To begin with, we want a clean Range, meaning nothing inside
    Set myRng = Nothing

    'So I am setting the cells I wish to use from the Excel Sheet Monthly Figures
    Set myRng = Sheets("Monthly Figures").Range("B5,B6,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B15,B17,B18,B19,B20,B22,B23,B25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'Error Handling message, just incase
    If myRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    html_text = _
        "<font style='size:22px;weight:bold;'>**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures</font></br></br>"

    'NOTE: UPDATED THE LOOP AND HTML BELOW FOR BODY

    For Each Row In myRng.Rows
        For Each cell In Row.Cells
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<font style='size:18px;'>Month: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<font style='size:14px;'>Purchases Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Purchases Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Paid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Unpaid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Paid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Unpaid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Tax Receipts Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Float Money Starting Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Float Money Current Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Float Money In: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Float Money Out: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Cash Sales Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Cash Sales Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></br></br>"
            html_text = html_text & _
                "Months Evaluation: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
                cell.Text & _
                "</font></font></br>"
        Next cell
    Next Row

    'Some more sexy error handling
    Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    On Error GoTo Error_Handling

    'Sets our SMTP settings so we can send emails....and stuff.
    Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    CDO_Config.Load -1

    Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

    With SMTP_Config
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "**HIDDEN**"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "HIDDEN"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "HIDDEN"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
        .Update
    End With

    'This is where I made myself a cup of tea because I was getting tired! :D
    With CDO_Mail
        Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
    End With

    'And finally this is the email subject, to, from, body, cc, and any bcc
    CDO_Mail.Subject = "HIDDEN"
    CDO_Mail.From = "HIDDEN"
    CDO_Mail.To = "HIDDEN"
    CDO_Mail.HTMLBody = html_text
    CDO_Mail.CC = ""
    CDO_Mail.BCC = ""

    'Send the message
    CDO_Mail.Send

    'Error handling
    Error_Handling:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub


Sub Print_Figures_Click()
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut ' print
End Sub
```

(**Note:** This code has been updated 18/07/2018 to show an amended `For Each Row In myRng.Rows` & HTML being used, but still requires further amendments.)

**This 'may' be a possible part-solution but I am not sure how to implement it correctly:**

```
' Declare an array with 18 elements including 0 as the first.
Dim my_body_text(17) As String

' Assign values to each element.
my_body_text(0) = _
    "<font style='size:22px;weight:bold;'>**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(1) = my_body_text(0) & _
    "<font style='size:18px;'>Month: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(2) = my_body_text(1) & _
    "<font style='size:14px;'>Purchases Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(3) = my_body_text(2) & _
    "Purchases Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(4) = my_body_text(3) & _
    "Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(5) = my_body_text(4) & _
    "Paid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(6) = my_body_text(5) & _
    "Unpaid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(7) = my_body_text(6) & _
    "Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(8) = my_body_text(7) & _
    "Paid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(9) = my_body_text(8) & _
    "Unpaid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(10) = my_body_text(9) & _
    "Tax Receipts Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(11) = my_body_text(10) & _
    "Float Money Starting Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(12) = my_body_text(11) & _
    "Float Money Current Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(13) = my_body_text(12) & _
    "Float Money In: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(14) = my_body_text(13) & _
    "Float Money Out: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(15) = my_body_text(14) & _
    "Cash Sales Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br>"
my_body_text(16) = my_body_text(15) & _
    "Cash Sales Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></br></br>"
my_body_text(17) = my_body_text(16) & _
    "Months Evaluation: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & _
    cell.Text & _
    "</font></font></br>"

' Create a 10-element integer array.
Dim i As Integer

' Add info & increase by 1 each time.
For i = 0 To 17
    '
    ' ADD THE CELL INTO STRING HERE SOMEHOW!
    '
    '
    my_body_text(i) = my_body_text(i) + 1
Next i
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Update on the code being used now as of 19/07/2018:**

This version is correctly sending the email, and correctly sending each of the `Cell.Text`, but for some reason it is not sending the `<font>` tags or the strings within the `<font>` tags.
For example: instead of placing the full string `"Tax Receipts Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text` from `Case 10` into the html_text, it is placing: `Month:` from the `Case 1` without the `<font>` tags in **every time**, and then adding the correctly updated `Cell.Text` afterwards.
Its almost working... Can you advise what I am missing?

(And is there a way to put copy the currency symbol also? As only a question mark displays for currency symbols other than $ or £ copied. I know the unicode for what I am wanting is U+0E3F. Can this just be placed in a string?)

```
'Begin Email button
Sub Email_Figures_Click()

'Dims the things we need
Dim CDO_Mail As Object
Dim CDO_Config As Object
Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBcc As String
Dim myRng As Range
Dim CaseRange As Integer

'To begin with, we want a clean Range, meaning nothing inside
Set myRng = Nothing

'So I am setting the cells I wish to use from the Excel Sheet Monthly Figures
Set myRng = Sheets("Monthly Figures").Range("B2,B5,B6,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B15,B17,B18,B19,B20,B22,B23,B25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Error Handling message, just incase
If myRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
End If

'Sets the email body title (inside the html_text)
html_text = "<font style='size:22px;weight:bold;'>**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures</font></br></br>"


'Defaults the CaseRange to 1
CaseRange = 1

For Each Row In myRng.Rows 'For each Row
    For Each Cell In Row.Cells 'And for each cell in the Row
        Select Case CaseRange 'Select a Case from our CaseRange
            Case 1
                html_text = html_text & "<font style='size:18px;'>Month: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            Case 2
                html_text = html_text & "<font style='size:14px;'>Purchases Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 3
                html_text = html_text & "Purchases Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            Case 4
                html_text = html_text & "Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 5
                html_text = html_text & "Paid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 6
                html_text = html_text & "Unpaid Invoices Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 7
                html_text = html_text & "Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 8
                html_text = html_text & "Paid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 9
                html_text = html_text & "Unpaid Sales Invoices Count: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            Case 10
                html_text = html_text & "Tax Receipts Total: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            Case 11
                html_text = html_text & "Float Money Starting Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 12
                html_text = html_text & "Float Money Current Balance: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 13
                html_text = html_text & "Float Money In: <font style='weight:bold;color:green;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 14
                html_text = html_text & "Float Money Out: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br></br>"
            Case 15
                html_text = html_text & "Cash Sales Total: <font style='weight:bold;color:red;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></br>"
            Case 16
                html_text = html_text & "Months Evaluation: <font style='weight:bold;'>" & Cell.Text & "</font></font></br>"
            Case Else
               html_text = html_text & "Error: Cannot find the Case Cell Number to import to email"
        End Select
    Next Cell 'Jump to the next cell and repeat the the process
Next Row ' Jump to next Row and repeat the process


'error handling
Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling

'Sets our SMTP settings so we can send emails
Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1

Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

'Settings for sending the email
With SMTP_Config
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
 .Update
End With

'Sets the config
With CDO_Mail
 Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With

'Defines Email Attributes
CDO_Mail.Subject = "**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures"
CDO_Mail.From = "**HIDDEN**"
CDO_Mail.To = "**HIDDEN**"
CDO_Mail.HTMLBody = html_text
CDO_Mail.CC = ""
CDO_Mail.BCC = ""

'Sends the email
CDO_Mail.Send

'Error handling and email sent successfully confirmation
Error_Handling:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description Else MsgBox "Message sent successfully"

'End the button
End Sub


Sub Print_Figures_Click()
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut ' print
End Sub
```

**Screenshot below of the email output**

[image: Image of Email output]

**Dummy Data that is being passed by email**

[image: Summary dummy data]

**Updated 20/07/2017 to make my Case selction more like what @Paul has suggested**

@Paul

**Notes & Updates:** 
CSS style related html doesn't seem to work. For example: `<h3></h>` & `<font style='weight:bold;color:green;'></font>`, These simply do not want to work within the Case Selections. I would have to use `<b><font color='green' size='14'>`. This being said, it picks up the **very first** HTML tag in the first Case **only** that is being used and applies to everything in html_text after that. Despite having closing HTML tags!

I don't see any difference with using my 1 Range of all the cells, and using your 2 Ranges , 1 for Headers and 1 for Totals. It seems to do the same thing. I have tried both options though just to eliminate this option. I have then gone and added all *Title Headings* for each total into the Range also, so the range cell count has now doubled.

From your last update to your answer explains the Cases a lot more than what I was able to find anywhere else online, so thanks for that. I have now changed my Cases to make them similar to your own as much as possible.

**Below is the full code to date:**

```
'Begin Email button
Sub Email_Figures_Click()

'Dims the things we need
Dim CDO_Mail As Object
Dim CDO_Config As Object
Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBcc As String
Dim myRng As Range
Dim CaseRange As Integer

'To begin with, we want a clean Range, meaning nothing inside
Set myRng = Nothing

'So I am setting the cells I wish to use from the Excel Sheet Monthly Figures
Set myRng = Sheets("Monthly Figures").Range("A2,B2,A5,B5,A6,B6,A8,B8,A9,B9,A10,B10,A11,B11,A12,B12,A13,B13,A15,B15,A17,B17,A18,B18,A19,B19,A20,B20,A22,B22,A23,B23,A25,B25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


'Error Handling message, just incase
If myRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
End If

'Sets the email body title (inside the html_text)
html_text = "<html><body><h1>**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures</h1><br><br /><br><br />"


'Defaults the CaseRange to 1
CaseRange = 1

For Each Row In myRng.Rows 'For each Row

    For Each Cell In Row.Cells 'And for each cell in the Row
    Select Case CaseRange
        'Month Title Heading
        Case 1
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h2>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</h2>"
        'The Month
        Case 2
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h2>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</h2>"
        'All other Title Headings
        Case 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h3>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</h3>"
        'All the Black Totals
        Case 4, 6, 8, 14, 20, 22, 24, 32, 34
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h3>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</h3>"
        'All the Red Totals
        Case 12, 18, 28, 30
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h3><font color='red'>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</font></h3>"
        'All the Green Totals
        Case 10, 16, 26
            html_text = html_text & _
                "<h3><font color='green'>" & _
                    Cell.Text & _
                "</font></h3>"
    End Select

Next Cell 'Jump to the next cell and repeat the the process
Next Row ' Jump to next Row and repeat the process

'Close our html & body tags before adding to email
html_text = html_text & "</body></html>"


'error handling
Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling

'Sets our SMTP settings so we can send emails
Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1

Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

'Settings for sending the email
With SMTP_Config
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "**HIDDEN**"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
 .Update
End With

'Sets the config
With CDO_Mail
 Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With

'Defines Email Attributes
CDO_Mail.Subject = "**HIDDEN** Monthly Figures"
CDO_Mail.From = "**HIDDEN**"
CDO_Mail.To = "**HIDDEN**"
CDO_Mail.HTMLBody = html_text
CDO_Mail.CC = ""
CDO_Mail.BCC = ""

'Sends the email
CDO_Mail.Send

'Error handling and email sent successfully confirmation
Error_Handling:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description Else MsgBox "Message sent successfully"

'End the button
End Sub
```

**And here is the outputted email:**

[image: Email Output]

Comment: Not tested: Deleting all your next i's and adding only one after the last html_text =...?  (it's only one For Next loop)

Comment: Start here: [Excel VBA Loops](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Comment: Doesn’t work. I don’t/didn’t fully understand how the next I worked, the link below sheds some light though that @JosephC has mentioned, thanks.

Comment: Regarding update: Why bother? You've just written a perfectly good loop into a serial list of statements but using the same cell each time. I would recommend that you nip off and have a read of the documentation for VBA first. `Select Case` and `For To Next` are your friends here. I specifically used `For To Next` as it gives you index numbers to compare against...

Comment: Why bother? Trial and error! As I am not fluent in VBA at all. StackOverflow is about learning & sharing knowledge after-all. I have been trying to solve this small section for nearly 3 days. I have attempt lots of different solutions I have found online, but nothing seems to fit what I am looking for. And this is only a small part of the whole workbook functionality.
I will read up on the Select Class and For To Next and then give it ago. - I may be back :P  If I manage to sort it I will click to accept your answer for the help you have given. Thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks in regards to the `Select Case`, I have managed to work it out and I have amend my code to show this. I I have added an update to the original question also. The email is sending correctly, the `Cell.Text` data is input correctly, but the html & string before and after the `Cell.Text` do not. Have you any further advice to resolve the html strings being passed?

Comment: This is obviously some kind of financial report. Does your spread sheet have the names you use in your email at the top of the respective columns on the worksheet?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Perhaps this will look cleaner for you.  Little tip - all of your columns should have headers associated to them to describe what the data pertains to - use them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those `Next` statements are going to cause you a problem.

What I would say is put the title for the statistic in the cell above, then you can include that in the range.  From there it's simply a case of...

```vba
Const colStart As Integer = 5: Const colEnd As Integer = 25
Const rowTitle As Integer = 2: Const rowData As Integer = 3

Dim x As Integer
Dim msg As String
For x = colStart To colEnd
    If Cells(rowTitle, x) <> "" Then
        msg = msg & Cells(rowTitle, x) & _
            "<font style='weight:bold;size:18px;'>" & Cells(rowData, x) & "</font>"
    End If
Next x
```

Alternatively you could create a list of strings that you want to use and split them...

```
Dim strTitles() As String
strTitles = Split("List of titles,and other,things", ",")
Dim x As Integer
For x = colStart To colEnd
    ...
```

Or you could keep a reference sheet for things like titles and switch between the two using a similar method to that mentioned above...

```
For x = colStart To colEnd
    If Worksheets(0).Cells(rowTitle, x) <> "" Then
        msg = msg & Worksheets(0).Cells(rowTitle, x) & _
            "<font style='weight:bold;size:18px;'>" & _
            Worksheets(1).Cells(rowData, x) & _
            "</font>"
    End If
Next x
```

Yet another option would be to have a worksheet to control *all* of your settings.  For example...

[image: Settings worksheet]

And then read the values from this to get your values from the appropriate location...

```
Dim strSht As String
Dim row As Integer, cols As Integer, x As Integer
strSheet = Worksheets("MySettings").Cells(1,1)
row = Worksheets("MySettings").Cells(2,1)
cols = Worksheets("MySettings").Cells(3,1)
For x = 4 to 3 + cols
    msg = msg & _
        "<strong>" & _
            Worksheets("MySettings").Cells(x,1) & _
        "</strong>" & _
        Worksheets(strSht).Cells(row, Worksheets("MySettings").Cells(x,1))
Next x
```

### In Response To Update (19/07/2018)

You've missed the point completely. There's absolutely no reason to have a loop if you're going to independently format every single string in this manner.

**Design**

Firstly, design is crucial - you simply do not want to be changing too many font settings. Rather than use `font-size: 22pt; weight: bold;`, consider using the `<h1>` tag.  Likewise for the slightly smaller font, use `<h2>`.  For anything that needs to stand out, use `<strong>`, and use `<em>` for anything that needs emphasising (you could use the `<b>` or `<i>` tags if you prefer, as their use is [becoming more accepted once again](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255366/why-are-the-b-and-i-tags-deprecated), though it's a love hate relationship with some, though in your case their use would be semantically specific). Changing font size way too many times makes your email more difficult to read.

If you have to use colour, then only use two - black and another colour. Again, changing the colour too frequently makes it messy (IMO). For instance, the financial developers that I know, tend to only use black and red, and guess which text is usually red?...

**Using `Select Case`**

The idea behind `Select Case` was to *limit* the amount of work you had to do.  In your case this simply isn't going to work unless you change your design. The reason I recommended it was to try and help you limit that amount of reformatting you were about to do.

`Select Case` is intended to work with a small number of options from a larger total.  For instance, in your case, you could have used...

```
Const rowHead As Integer = theRowNumberThatHasTheHeadingsOnIt
Dim rowData As Integer, colStart, colEnd
rowData = theRowNumberThatHasTheDataOnIt
colStart = theFirstColumnInTheList
colEnd = theLastColumnInTheList

Dim msgText As String
For x = colStart To colEnd
    Select Case x
        Case 1
            msgText = _
                "<h1>" & _
                    Cell(x, rowData) & _
                "</h1>"
        Case 2
            msgText = _
                "<h2>" & _
                    Cell(x, rowData) & _
                "</h2>"
        Case 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 16
            msgText = _
                "<strong>" & _
                    Cell(x, rowHead) & ": " & _
                "</strong>" & _
                Cell(x, rowData)
        Case 5, 8, 13
            msgText = _
                "<strong style='color: green;'>" & _
                    Cell(x, rowHead) & ": " & _
                "</strong>" & _
                Cell(x, rowData)
        Case 6, 9, 14, 15
            msgText = _
                "<strong style='color: red;'>" & _
                    Cell(x, rowHead) & ": " & _
                "</strong>" & _
                Cell(x, rowData)
        Case Else
            'Not really necessary, as you really want to skip any columns 
            'that you don't want, but your could put whatever doesn't quite 
            'fit here.
    End Select
    htmlMsg = htmlMsg & msgText
Next x
```

Notice the way I've used the `Select Case` statement - if particular columns in your list are not required in your email, then do not include them in the `Case` statement lines, that way they'll be skipped over.

I can't make it any clearer than that, really.

Good reading, though, would be the PHP `switch` statement that I included in the comments for your post.

Comment: The titles on the Excel sheet cannot be moved, however that shouldn’t be a problem as the cells used are a only a selection, not a full range as you can see in my question’s code. So I can include the titles in the selection and give it a try. I’ll post back afterwards if the method works. - I don’t like the idea of adding it as strings. It doesn’t seem a clean. An additional worksheet with the titles saved I think would be a ‘easy but sleazy’ way of doing things considering a list can be created inside the code itself, and it makes it bulky. An internal list I could try also. Thanks!

Comment: Haha! Nothing is wrong with sleazy I suppose. If it works, it works! I just prefer to steer a car with my hands than my feet. Gets the job done easier and more efficient :P

Comment: Hi @Paul, I tried your methods but I cannot see any way of of using individual html formatting for specific strings. I have minimized the html_text section & added some more html which is required, but instead of sending ALL strings each time, I only require the cell number to increase by 1 each time (i=i+1) and add to the correct string + html (string + html will also require a j=J+1 I assume? Still unsure how to implement this though.

Comment: All you have to do in your case is check the value of `x` ([`Select Case x`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/select-case-statement)) and compare it against a particular value and add the style to the font when necessary. It's really not rocket science, but I'm going to leave this for you to do. You might want to put your own hands on that steering wheel rather than the chauffeur using his feet!

Comment: In reply to the update you added for 19/07/2018. I have accomplished the html formats problem. I tried tags such as `<strong>`, `<h3>`, `</br>` ,`style='color: green;'` which I have found do not work. It will only accept `<b>` for bold, `<font size="18">`  for sizing, and `<font color='green'>` for coloring, and strangely enough it will accept `<br> but not </br>`.  Also, there are headings on other sheets, but the sheet that I have been asked to email is a summary of all the Totals from all sheets as a selection of cells. Hence no headings are available for the summary sheet.

Comment: Yes - it's `<br />` not `</br>`. Bold and italic are your preference.

Comment: ...and you could add a final summary sheet using the format you wish to display in the email and saving you lots of work.

Comment: I have added a second image of some dummy data being passed from the Summary Monthly Figures, and the styling is not my preference, its the directors. I previously asked on StackOverflow if there was a way to pass a range from excel to an email by button click while keeping formatting and received no response. :/

Comment: My Range and input is fully working now. There is only a problem with inputting the HTML into cases. Please see the question update and screenshot.

Comment: No formatting gets passed to the email, whether its from a summary sheet or not. This is why I am trying to add the HTML in with the Select Case.